# CumSum until certain value reached and then stop and print 'MAX'

Tags: python-3.x, cumsum

I have  list of numbers (0-100)

```
numbers = list(range(101))
```

then I need to take the CumSum until 1000 is reached and then stop the calculation and print 'max is reached'

```
np.cumsum(numbers)

array([   0,    1,    3,    6,   10,   15,   21,   28,   36,   45,   55,
     66,   78,   91,  105,  120,  136,  153,  171,  190,  210,  231,
    253,  276,  300,  325,  351,  378,  406,  435,  465,  496,  528,
    561,  595,  630,  666,  703,  741,  780,  820,  861,  903,  946,
    990, 1035, 1081, 1128, 1176, 1225, 1275, 1326, 1378, 1431, 1485,
   1540, 1596, 1653, 1711, 1770, 1830, 1891, 1953, 2016, 2080, 2145,
   2211, 2278, 2346, 2415, 2485, 2556, 2628, 2701, 2775, 2850, 2926,
   3003, 3081, 3160, 3240, 3321, 3403, 3486, 3570, 3655, 3741, 3828,
   3916, 4005, 4095, 4186, 4278, 4371, 4465, 4560, 4656, 4753, 4851,
   4950, 5050], dtype=int32)
```

Now I got the CumSum of the whole list

I was thinking about,

0 > 1000 ==> No. continue

0+1  > 1000 ==> No. continue

...

990 + 45 > 1000 ==> Yes. print 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
and stop the calculation

I expect something like this

```
array([   0,    1,    3,    6,   10,   15,   21,   28,   36,   45,   55,
         66,   78,   91,  105,  120,  136,  153,  171,  190,  210,  231,
        253,  276,  300,  325,  351,  378,  406,  435,  465,  496,  528,
        561,  595,  630,  666,  703,  741,  780,  820,  861,  903,  946,
        990])
MAX VALUE REACHED
```

Can someone help me to transform my idea into code?

thanks!

Comment: Any reason you want to use numpy here? Looks like you'd be better of with a basic for-loop, increment a counter and an if statement

Comment: No reason for numpy, this was my first idea

Comment: Well, numpy isn't meant for looping and is likely to be overkill then... set a counter to 0, loop over your range, add the number to your counter, check what your counter is, print the approrpiate message and break out of the loop if necessary... Start with the basic building blocks.

Comment: I made my problem more clear, I need to get the first values <1000 and then print the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something like this now:

```
def cumsum(x):
q = np.array(range (0,x))
z = q.cumsum()
v = np.clip(z, 0, 1000)
solution = ['MAX VALUE REACHED' if i == 1000 else i for i in v]
if x == 0:
    return[0]
else:
    return solution
```

My output is this

```
[0,
 1,
 3,
 6,
 10,
 15,
 21,
 28,
 36,
 45,
 55,
 66,
 78,
 91,
 105,
 120,
 136,
 153,
 171,
 190,
 210,
 231,
 253,
 276,
 300,
 325,
 351,
 378,
 406,
 435,
 465,
 496,
 528,
 561,
 595,
 630,
 666,
 703,
 741,
 780,
 820,
 861,
 903,
 946,
 990,
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED',
 'MAX VALUE REACHED']
```

Now I have to stop the calculation after one time 'MAX VALUE REACHED'
Any sugestions?

**Proposed alternative**

Rather than using `clip` create a new list that contains only the `cumsum` items that are less than 1,000, and when you encounter an item that is at least 1,000 break out of the loop.

```
import numpy as np

q = np.array(range(101)) 
z = q.cumsum()
temp = []
for _ in z:
    if _ < 1000:
        temp.append(_)
    else:
        break
solution = np.array(temp)
print (solution)
print('MAX VALUE REACHED')
```

Output:

```
[  0   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105 120 136 153
 171 190 210 231 253 276 300 325 351 378 406 435 465 496 528 561 595 630
 666 703 741 780 820 861 903 946 990]
MAX VALUE REACHED
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that, by now you have something like this, given Mr Clement's comment.

```
>>> total = 0
>>> i = 0
>>> while total < 1000:
...     total += i
...     i += 1
... 
>>> print (total)
1035
```

But someone should, sooner or later, suggest that you look carefully at the itertools library, as well as numpy. Your code can be written more compactly, like this.

```
>>> from itertools import count, accumulate, dropwhile
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: x<1000, accumulate(count())))
1035
```

This is known as [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). `count` is a so-called generator that produces a potentially infinite series of numbers, in this case, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... . `accumulate` produces the potentially infinite series of sums of these. `dropwhile` arranges to ignore numbers in this series that fail to satisfy the `lambda` condition. And finally `next` produces the next item in the resulting series of numbers.

Comment: But that doesn't appear to be syntactically valid.

Comment: I wrote something in a new answer, can you check it?

Comment: Alternative suggested.